maya python - How to enable color correction in render settings
How do I enable an change the color correction settings in common render settings in Python?
I can access all other attributes using the defaultRenderGlobals, but can't seem to find the color corrections attributes.
Any clue?
enter image description here
I have looked in all render nodes in my scene.
I have echoed all commands while turning it on, but it doesn't show me anything useful.
I have tried:
cmds.setAttr("defaultRenderGlobals.outputColorProfile", 2).
but it doesn't seem do anything.
I tried:
cmds.colorManagementPrefs(e=True, q=True, cmEnabled=True, outputTransformEnabled=True)

withtout luck.
I have roamed the depth of the internet to find a solution.

import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.colorManagementPrefs(edit=True, outputTransformEnabled=True) this worked fine for me
